# Error to try update cache apollo and draw the UI

Tags: reactjs, graphql, browser-cache, apollo

I am starting in the development of applications with apollo, react and graphql, I have created a form to capture brands of vehicle and show them in a table. When you start the page for the first time, it shows the table well, but when I try to record a new brand it throws me the following image. Please I need help.

[image]

this is my code

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Query, Mutation } from 'react-apollo';
import BrandItem from '../models/BrandItem';
import * as BrandService from '../services/BrandService';

export class Brand extends Component {
  render() {
    let input;

    return (
      <div className="divform">
        <Mutation mutation={BrandService.ADD_BRAND}
          update={(cache, { data: { addBrand } }) => {
            const { brands } = cache.readQuery({ query: BrandService.BRAND_QUERY });
            cache.writeData({
              query: BrandService.BRAND_QUERY,
              data: { brands: brands.concat([addBrand]) },
            });
          }}
        >
          {
            (addBrand, { data }) => (
              <form onSubmit={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                addBrand({ variables: { description: input.value } });
                console.log(data);
                input.value = '';
              }}>
                <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
                <input type="text" id="description" name="description" required ref={node => { input = node; }} />
                <input type="submit" value="Send" />
              </form>
            )
          }

        </Mutation>
        <div>
          <Fragment>
            <Query query={BrandService.BRAND_QUERY}>
              {
                ({ loading, error, data }) => {
                  if (loading) return <div><h4>loading....</h4></div>
                  if (error) console.log(error);

                  return <Fragment>
                    <table>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Id</th>
                          <th>Description</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {
                          data.brands.map(brand => (
                            <BrandItem key={brand.id} brand={brand} />
                          ))
                        }
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </Fragment>
                }
              }
            </Query>
          </Fragment>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Brand
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the only place you use map is here.

```
{
    data.brands.map(brand => (
        <BrandItem key={brand.id} brand={brand} />
    ))
}
```

Therefore, data.brands must be null or undefined.
I would check the query `BrandService.BRAND_QUERY` and check it has brands defined in the query. It may help if you added a `console.log(data)` to double check the structure of the response.

If it makes sense that there are no brands returned in some cases. The simplest way to do that would be to do.

```
{
    data.brands && data.brands.map(brand => (
        <BrandItem key={brand.id} brand={brand} />
    ))
}
```

However the best thing to do depends on your app.